# Objective-C - Errors when passing a variable into function

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cordova

What is the easiest way to pass a var into another function ?

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager 
    didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation 
           fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {

   NSLog(@"%@", started);
}
```

I tried:

Defined a global vars:

```
extern NSString *started;
```

When I set the NSString directly and passing into another function, it works well:

```
-(void) startTracking:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command {
  started = @"testing";
}
```

But it doesn't work:

```
-(void) startTracking:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command {

  NSString* myarg = [command.arguments objectAtIndex:0]; // http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.5.0/guide_plugin-development_ios_index.md.html#Developing%20a%20Plugin%20on%20iOS_writing_an_ios_cordova_plugin
  started = myarg;
}
```

(I'm a objective-C beginner, don't understand it well)

EDIT: Seems like it only crashed when I put the app into background.

Comment: what you trying to do by this"[command.arguments objectAtIndex:0];" taking value of command in myarg?

Comment: @PrakashDesai, this is getting parameter from PhoneGap plugin.

Comment: **Important nuance** :  These aren't "functions" but "methods".  Methods are like functions except that they are tied to objects and have access to its *state* (any variable). Rewording:  Functions have access to passed variable (parameters) and global variable (try to avoid/minimize that last one);  Methods have access the passed all those plus its object's variables.

Comment: @Qooe What `error` you are getting ?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on wether you are using ARC, you have to retain the object. You'll probably want to use a property on your class:

in your header:

```
@property(strong) NSString *started;
```

in implementation:

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager 
didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation 
       fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {

 NSLog(@"%@", self.started);
}

-(void) startTracking:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command {
  self.started = @"testing";
}

-(void) startTracking:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command {

 NSString* myarg = [command.arguments objectAtIndex:0];
 self.started = myarg;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Mate, seems like you want to track the date you started receiving location information.

How about doing it like this:

```
// Your .h file
@interface MyClass <CLLocationManagerDelegate>
{
    BOOL hasStartedUpdatingLocation;
    NSDate *startDate;

    CLLocationManager *locationManager;
}

...

// Your .m file
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager 
    didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation 
           fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation 
{
    // ---------------------------------------------------------------
    // if has NOT started updating location, record start date
    // otherwise, do not execute this if statement
    // ---------------------------------------------------------------
    if(!hasStartedUpdatingLocation)
    {
        hasStartedUpdatingLocation = YES;

        // this if statement should only execute once
        startDate = [NSDate date]; // get the current date and time
    }
    else
    {
        // do something else
    }
}
```

Comment: AFAIK, You could also remove the BOOL and change the if-statement to something like `if (startDate == nil) { ... }`. :-)

Comment: Thanks @Zhang, want to pass users token into didUpdateToLocation

Comment: What's user's token? Is that something that will never change? You can store it inside NSUserDefaults and fetch it back out. Otherwise, if it's just temporary, you can declare an instance variable in your view controller header file and store the user token there, that way it's accessible in your entire view controller.